# Is a final -u in Semitic languages known outside of Akkadian?

Tags: phonology, historical-linguistics, cases, semitic-languages, akkadian

Consider Akkadian *bētu* vs. Hebrew *bayit* (בַּיִת) (meaning "house") and Akkadian *daltu* vs. Hebrew *delet* (דֶּלֶת) (meaning "door"). Are these endings known outside of Akkadian? If so, when did they disappear? Would they have been present in the language(s) of the Proto-Sinaitic inscriptions?

Answer (score 12):

That Akkadian word-final *-u* is the Nominative case ending, the other case endings being *-a* for Accusative and *-i* for Genitive. Thus, the [case forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akkadian_language#Case,_number_and_gender) of the noun *bētu* 'house' are:

> Nom.: bēt**u**
>   Acc.: bēt**a**
>   Gen.: bēt**i**

Exactly the same case endings are still present in Literary Arabic (Modern Standard Arabic), although in most spoken Arabic dialects they are lost. The declension of the Arabic noun بَيْتُ ([baytu](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D8%A8%D9%8A%D8%AA#Declension)) 'house', in the Construct state where no other suffix follows the case vowel:

> Nom.:  بَيْتُ (bayt**u**)
>   Acc.: بَيْتَ (bayt**a**)
>   Gen.: بَيْتِ (bayt**i**)

As for Hebrew, it has no noun case category whatsoever, hence the absence of the case endings. Hebrew is a Northwest Semitic language. Case endings are found in Northwest Semitic languages in the second millennium BCE, but disappear almost totally afterwards.`*`

So we can see that originally all the Semitic languages used to have case, but the tendency is to get rid of it, which was done in Hebrew first (no cases already in Biblical Hebrew), Arabic dialects lost it after the 7th century. Ge'ez, a dead liturgical South Semitic language (Arabic is also a South Semitic language) has (had) [just two cases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ge%CA%BDez#Nouns) — unmarked Nominative, ቤት (bet) 'house', and Accusative with the suffix *-a*, ቤተ (bet**a**), which is the same Accusative suffix as in Akkadian and Arabic.

As for the Proto-Sinaitic, it is definitely problematic to speak about *vowels* in Semitic consonantal alphabets.

---

`*` Sáenz-Badillos, Angel (1993). *A History of the Hebrew Language*. Cambridge University Press. Pages 36–38,43–44,47–50.

Comment: Can we say whether or not the language(s) of the Proto-Sinaitic inscriptions would have had these case endings based on language-relationship and chronological considerations?

Comment: @user17584 We know almost nothing about the language of the Proto-Sinaitic inscriptions, due to the scarcity of data. And as Yellow Sky mentioned, the inscriptions themselves offer no information about vowels, only consonants.

Comment: @user17584 - If the earliest Proto-Sinaitic inscriptions were really made in the early 2nd millennium BCE, and if their language is really Semitic, it is pretty possible that language did have the case endings, but not necessarily — since we know little about that language, it can well come out to be the first Semitic language to loose those endings, earlier than those inscriptions were made. To put it short, it's all just hypotheses.

Comment: What would a word ending in a vowel like פאה "corner" look like with such a Nominative case ending? Would a word for "these two" related to the name of ז have one?

Comment: @user17584 We can't say with any certainty what "Hebrew with case endings" would look like, because by the time Hebrew is attested, it had lost them. But if you want to know about different types of case-marking in Proto-Semitic, I'd recommend asking a separate question for that, since it's too elaborate a topic to explain in comments.

Comment: @user17584 - Here's a [very good book for you](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xBbvuewrscXS5Iy39e9fYmFRymINQtaU/view?usp=sharing) — "_Case in Semitic: Roles, Relations, and **Reconstruction**"_ by Rebecca Hasselbach, 2013, Oxford University Press. I hope, you'll find mush insight in it. Enjoy!

Comment: Actually, in Arabic it is (indefinite) baytun, baytan, bayti, (determined) albaytu, albayta, albayta.

Comment: @fdb - I gave the forms in the Construct state where neither the nunation nor the definite article distracts attention from the case vowel suffix.

Comment: @YellowSky. Maybe you should have said that.

Comment: @fdb - OK, I've edited my answer. Actually, if one opens my link that precedes the declension of the Arabic noun, one will see at once that those forms are of the Construct state, it's written there.

Comment: Obviously not the same _-u_ as in the question, but perhaps noteworthy that _-u_ is very common in some Ethiopic languages (most prominently Amharic, but also Ge’ez to some degree) since it functions as the definite article there. In Amharic, for example, ቤቱ _betu_ means ‘the house’, and (just to confuse matters even more), the definite object is marked by _-n_, so ቤቱን _betun_, which in Arabic would be the nominative indefinite, is the accusative definite in Amharic.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - I decided not to mention that in my answer since the Amharic _-u_ is really unrelated to the original Semitic Nominative case _-u_, it is an Amharic innovation, as stated in the book I gave link to in the comment above, page 29.

Comment: @YellowSky Well, partly an Amharic innovation anyway; it’s an areal feature that Amharic takes part in.

Comment: I'm sure I've read a suggestion that the "he-locative" suffix used with place-names and some common nouns in Biblical Hebrew is a relic of the inherited Accusative; but I can't find where. I thought it was in Hetzron's _The Semitic Languages_, but Steiner in his account of Biblical Hebrew says that "the old accusative ending _*+a_ is gone, leaving only a few frozen relics behind" without identifying those relics, and his account of the "postposition" _+åʰ_" does not say anything about its origin, so maybe not.

Comment: @ColinFine - _Case in Semitic: Roles, Relations, and Reconstruction_ by Rebecca Hasselbach, 2013 says, "Hebrew retained some vestiges of original case markers in the linking vowels before pronominal suffixes, such as _malkēk_ ‘your (fem sing) king’ < *_malkik_ < *_malki-ki_ (gen), _malkō_ ‘his (masc sing) king’ < *_malkuh_ < *_malku-hu_ (nom), and _malkāk_ ‘your (masc sing) king’ < *_malkaka_ (acc)."

Comment: @ColinFine, Also, in the same book, "In addition, Hebrew has a directional morpheme _–āh_, indicating direction towards an object, as in _yāmmāh_ ‘to the sea.’ This directional morpheme is etymologically connected to the directional morpheme _–h_ found in Ugaritic and the Akkadian term-adv _–iš_." As I understand, the author suggests that the _ā_ in _–āh_ is a trace of the accusative case suffix.

Comment: the genitive -i seems to have been retained relatively late (albeit probably not actually as -i) in Phoenician because possessive suffixes take their postvocalic forms (i.e. the same as the object suffixes on verbs) when attached to genitive nouns, rather than their usual forms on nominative/accusative nouns. I believe this is in both the Cambridge Atlas of the World's Ancient Languages and Krahmalkov's grammar

Answer (score 5):

The ending of the nominative singular -u, -un, -um is visible in Akkadian, Arabic, and Ugaritic. It was probably spoken in other languages (e.g. Ancient South Arabian, Ancient Aramaic), but not visible because of the consonantal script.

Answer (score 2):

It can be noted that this system Sg -u (short), Pl -aw (> long u:) is also attested in Hieroglyphic Egyptian.

Comment: What evidence is there that Hieroglyphic Egyptian had _Sg -u (short)_? There were no vowels marked in Hieroglyphic Egyptian.

Comment: It can be reconstructed from Coptic words, though it is not an easy job.

Comment: There are also a very few clay tablets from Tell el Amarna that transcribe Egyptian words in cuneiform, which are helpful for this.

Comment: It should be noted that Egyptian, while an Afro-Asiatic language, is not in the Semitic subfamily. This would be like asking a question about Romance languages and then answering, "Note that in Russian....". It's certainly interesting but not really an answer to the question asked

Comment: Egyptian supports the idea that Semitic -u /-aw is more ancient than Semitic. I never implied that Egyptian was a member of Semitic.